# Website modification

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web site that can verify your web pages. Specifically, let's say you created a web page on Monday and you want your users to be assured that when they view the same page on Tuesday, that it's the same page that was posted on Mondyy (without any modifications).

Comment: I hate being the bearer of bad news. There are web apps for lots of special cases, but this case seems unique. On the plus side, maybe your web page's users are not interested in whether the site's the same as yesterday, so you can just skip this problem entirely? Good luck! ~S

Comment: There is no web site for this, but it might be possible to set something up with a bit of server side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

There are services which can notify you of updates to website changes.

Google had such a service in Google Reader, but they recently (in the last month) removed the facility.

A quick search for "monitor website changes" bought up the following. I don't know how good they are or if they'll do what you want.

http://www.changedetection.com/
http://www.watchthatpage.com/
http://www.ghacks.net/2009/09/07/monitor-website-changes/

In response to what I think you're asking for - The easiest way to make users feel comfortable that a webpage hasn't changed would be to provide a "last changed" date on the webpage and an option to view prior changes.

Most Wikis provide this functionality, and some of these can be configured to only allow known users (e.g. you) to change pages.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a report type setup rather than a pure web page.

You need to pass a date (or similar) on the query string, and return the data (page) associated with that date. This can be done purely as a web page, or you could set up a reporting solution that does it - the advantage of the reporting solution is that it should have multiple formats that it can export the page to (like Excel or PDF).

You also don't need another website to test and validate your pages - that sort of testing can be very easily done by humans or by the testing tools built into products like Visual Studio.